# Use multiple 'workflows' in gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Lets Imagine I want to have 2 different CI Pipelines in gitlab. The first one should start with every push on any branch the other one only when the commit title ends with deploy.

How do I realise that?

So my Idea:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - pre
  - build


include:
  - local: ci/a.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: ci/b.gitlab-ci.yml
```

**a.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
workflow:
  rules:
  # only triggered by "-deploy" at the end of commit 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE == /-deploy$/ 

test-job1:
  stage: pre
  script:
    - echo "Workflow a runs pre."
  tags:
    - x86

test-job2:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Workflow a runs build."
  tags:
    - x86
```

**b.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
workflow:
  rules:
  # only triggered if commit does not end with  "-deploy"  
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /-deploy$/ 

test-job1:
  stage: pre
  script:
    - echo "Workflow b runs pre."
  tags:
    - x86

test-job2:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Workflow b runs build."
  tags:
    - x86
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To achieve the effect you want, your best bet would be to [use `include:rules:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-rules-with-include) for this instead of `workflow:rules:`.

I believe you also may have a small error in the regex matching rule. You probably wanted to be using the regex match operator (`=~` i.e., does match the pattern) in the first case and the negative match re operator (`!~` i.e., does *not* match the pattern) in the second case.

```yaml
include:
  - local: ci/a.gitlab-ci.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /-deploy$/
  - local: ci/b.gitlab-ci.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE !~ /-deploy$/
```

Then remove the `workflow:rules:` from each respective template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just tested it, but somehow neither a or b gets triggered. Im not sure if there is a problem with the the regex expression or the rules

Comment: Strange. At least one of them should always be included (since each rule is a logical inverse of the other) @GianAlessio try removing the `$` from the pattern and see if that helps. Also make sure that you removed the use of `workflow:rules:` from the files!

Comment: it works! I think you should delete the quotation marks in your answer and its perfect

Comment: @GianAlessio thanks for testing that, glad it worked. Made the edit as you suggested.

Comment: This is great. Just to supplement this answer. If you have say 4/5/6/7 rules but some of them are global. Use the include local rules for the specific ones and then the general ones leave as workflow:rules

Thankyou @sytech

Comment: what if you want to include (say) three local files for one rule? the files are placed in a way that cannot be referenced with a wildcard - would require separate `local: path/to/file.yml`

Comment: @kappacake I'd have to double check, but I believe you can use an array for included files. You can at least for `include:project:file` I suspect the same is true for local includes.